# Why can’t I update the BIOS from the internal storage?

Tags: bios, updates, flashing

My ASUS EZ Flash 3 BIOS utility lists internal storage (SSD/HDD) devices as well as USBs, and it gives me the option to read BIOS flash files from the internal storage as well. But when I confirm that I want to read it, it fails. Why must it only work from a USB?

Comment: It fails _how_?

Comment: Doesn't really give me any details, just says "reading failed" or something like that

Comment: What file system are these internal disk?  In most cases the firmware can only read FAT32 in a case like this.  While Linux can read NTFS it’s not a perfect implementation, likewise, FAT32 more or less is an fully documented standard.

Comment: I use my ESP on my UEFI system for the Asus update files. Since Ubuntu, I do have to change permissions to allow me to write to ESP.  I have not used USB flash drive, but it would also have to be FAT32 to work with UEFI.